# Play 2.3 Validate Json Request Body

Tags: java, json, validation, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to use the validation annotations within a pojo object by sending json in the body of the request and converting the json to the pojo object.  What I would like to do is have the service consuming this json to return a bad request if the object is not valid.  Does anyone know how to go about doing this?  I've seen plenty of tutorials that show how to do form validation using the annotations, but what about just a simple json request?

POJO Object:

```
import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;

public class TestObject {

    @Required
    @Min(0)
    public Integer testInt;

    public Integer getTestInt() {
        return testInt;
    }

    public void setTestInt(Integer testInt) {
        this.testInt = testInt;
    }

}
```

I could probably look at every element by parsing the json and validate it that way, but that seems ridiculous...

```
import models.Domain;
import play.libs.Json;
import play.mvc.BodyParser;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

public class TestController extends Controller {

    @BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.Json.class, maxLength = 10 * 1024)
    public static Result create() {

        JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();

        TestObject testObject = Json.fromJson(json, TestObject.class);

        //would like to validate the object here, based on annotations
        //in the bean object...

        //only if the object is valid, return ok...
        return ok(json);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Peace!!

Since Play 2.5 `Form.form(...)` is deprecated.

Here is how you should do it now:

```
private FormFactory formFactory;

@Inject
YourContructor(FormFactory formFactory){
    this.formFactory
}


@BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.Json.class, maxLength = 10 * 1024)
public static Result create() {

    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();

    Form<TestObject > TestObjectValidationForm = formFactory.form(TestObject .class)
                                                            .bind(json);
    if(TestObjectValidationForm .hasErrors())
        return badRequest("Invalid");

    TestObject testObject = Json.fromJson(json, TestObject.class);

    //only if the object is valid, return ok...
    return ok(json);
}
```

Anyway, I don't really like to use form to do it... there is no better option?

Answer (score 1):

this is what i'll do

```
@BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.Json.class, maxLength = 10 * 1024)
public static Result create() {

    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();

    //this is not neccessary for validation except maybe to be sure the json can be 
    //mapped back to pojo before validating then you'll have to wrap     
    //this statement in a try catch so you can recover from any errors during mapping

    //TestObject testObject = Json.fromJson(json, TestObject.class);

    Form<TestObject> testObjectForm = Form.form(TestObject.class);
    Form<TestObject> testObjForm = testObjectForm.bind(json);

    if(testObjForm.hasErrors){
       doStuff()
    }else{
        return ok(json);
    }
}
```